# Writing in "First person implied"

Tags: style

As far as I know a pronoun "I" is usually omitted when personal achievements are being described (writing in "First person implied"). For example it's better to write:

> Performed a review of the project's source code.

than:

> I performed a review of the project's source code.

But the second statement I want to write is

> For each review issue **I proposed**  a way to fix it.

and it just seems to me that omitting "I" here looks a little unusual:

> For each review issue **proposed** a way to fix it.

Am I right? And If I am, then what is the correct, natural way to write that?

Comment: In some styles of CV or resumé, "First person implied" is usual in extremely condensed forms such as bullet lists.  You might consider "Proposed fixes for each review issue."  Whether it's better than standard sentence grammar is a style and context question.

Answer (score 0):

These sentences cannot be without a subject, so you always need to use "I."

> **I** performed a review of the project's source code.
>
> For each review issue, **I** proposed a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Developing Jonathango's comment! (Note the implied subject!)

This question is all about style and context. A lengthy CV is more likely to bore than interest a prospective employer.

So if you wish to present a list of achievements and experiences, the snappier and more eye-catching the better. Bullet points work well in this context:

My experience in national garment sales with X company includes:
 * 4 years in garment sales
 * 3 years as department manager
 * 2 years store manager
 * 4 years regional manager

and so on.

It's perfectly clear that you are listing your personal experience even though you are using neither pronouns nor verbs.

This style makes it quick and easy for the employer to take in, which is important when there are  hundreds or thousands of applications to be considered for a position.

The considerations are to be consistent, brief and clear - and of course it helps if you don't make any grammatical or spelling mistakes along the way.

I could not improve on Jonathango's suggestion of :**Proposed fixes for each review issue**.